# Programmatically Define XAML Schema

Tags: c#, xaml

Context: Visual Studio 2012, C# 4.0

I want to allow developers to write some code in XAML files. However, I should be able to restrict the schema (not sure if this is correct word) that they use so that for each attribute, values automatically pop up in Intellisense

Comment: No, this is for a Web application, possibly to make development easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved as follows:

Have a class as below:

```
using MyNamespace
{
public class MyClass
{...}
}
```

Then, in the xaml file:

```
<MyClass xmlns="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly={assembly name in which this namespace exists"></MyClass>
```